# Can't handle exceptions in ada tasks

Tags: loops, select, task, call, ada

I have the following example:

```
with Ada.TEXT_IO;
use Ada.TEXT_IO;

procedure main is

  task Test is
    entry Call1;
    entry Call2;
  end Test;

  task body Test is
    Num : Integer := 5;
  begin
    loop
      select when Num < 5 =>
        accept Call1 do
          Put_Line("Call1 called!");
        end Call1;
      or when Num > 5 =>
        accept Call2 do
          Put_Line("Call2 called!");
        end Call2;
      or
        terminate;
      end select;
    end loop;
    exception when PROGRAM_ERROR => Put_Line("Nothing to call... :(");
  end Test;

begin
  Test.Call1;
end;
```

If I'm right, the task gets program_error when it can't call anything. When I run it, it stuck in an endless while loop. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You're not right.  What is the problem?

Comment: If I’m right in my assumption below that you’re exploring what happens if there are no open select alternatives, it would have helped if you’d said so instead of just "I have the following example". And if not, as Jacob says, what _is_ the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you’re trying to explore what happens when there are no open `select` alternatives as in [ARM 9.7.1(21)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-7-1.html#p21),

> The exception Program_Error is raised if all alternatives are closed and there is no else part.

The thing is, *`terminate` is a select alternative* ([(4)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-7-1.html#p4), ibid) and can’t be closed, so not all alternatives are closed and `Test` is sitting at the `terminate`, prepared to die when the main program exits. But the main program is sitting at `Test.Call1`. Deadlock.

If you eliminate the `or terminate`, you get the `Program_Error` you were expecting; the task dies, and the main program gets `Tasking_Error`.

In an ideal world the compiler would catch the fact that neither `accept` can ever be open; presumably no one has felt deeply enough to implement the check (normally the problem would be much less obvious).

Comment: For example, it is not obvious that `Num` will never change, in a real world program. Nor that the selective accept will be the only place the task is going to accept entry calls.

Comment: If I modify my code from this: or when Num > 5 => into this: or when Num > 4 => ? I will get endless loop. How can I handle that?

Comment: `Num > 5` (or `4`) is in the guard for `Call2` but your main program is trying for `Call1`. So you still have a deadlock (_not_ an endless loop! though they do look similar from the outside)